# Is there a way to loop through data in c# codebehind and pass that to a javascript createElement("div")

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need to get data from a database and insert it into a newly created div for each row of the database, creating a sort of dashboard to monitor up-time at different industrial sites.

I've already made this bit of code on the javascript side that displays a new div each time it passes through the loop (Displayed Below). The div generation works.

However, I am at a loss for how to loop through on the code behind side and pass that to javascript. I haven't done the database connection yet, I want to ensure the code is working before I start that.

```
  var jVar1= "";
  var jVar2= "";
  var jVar3= "";
  var jVar4= "";


 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

      var jVar1= "<h4>&nbsp<%=this.cVar1%>" + " - " + "<%=this.cVar2%></h4>";
      var jVar2= "<p><%=this.cVar3%></p>";
      var jVar3= "<p><%=this.cVar4%></p>";
      var jVar4= "<p><%=this.cVar5%></p>";     

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = "infoContainer";
      div.innerHTML = ""
      div.innerHTML = jVar1 + imgSelectedBasedOnCriteria + "<br />" + jVar2 + 
      jVar3 + jVar4;
      document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
 }
```

```cs
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {

                cVar1 = "Location";
                cVar2 = "LocationType";
                cVar3 = "Relevant database information";
                cVar4 = "Relevant database information";
                cVar5 = "Relevant database information";

            }
        }
```

My thinking, which is obviously wrong considering it doesn't work, was to loop through on the codebehind side and then pass that through to a javascript loop which would then create the div for each collection of variables.

Comment: `and pass that to javascript` are we talking rendering the data into the returned markup from the backup, or live updates via ajax? and please help me out, what template engie was this: `<%=this.cVar2%>`

Comment: Why not use a Gridview and Eval ? https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Difference-between-Eval-and-Bind-functions-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: I'm not familiar with ajax, I was thinking of storing the database data in an object array, and then, somehow, passing that to the javascript.

I'm pretty new to asp.net development, so I'm still trying to work out the tricks.

Comment: <%=this.variableName%> is a way of obtaining the variable from code behind in javascript.

Comment: @Matthew Evans I would usually, but the client request is for a specific dashboard look, if that can be done using gridview and eval then I will investigate.

Comment: This combination of JS and a serverside templating engie feels weird to me. I'd either put up a controller+action that I can call from the frontend, get the data as JSON and render that with JS, or I'd use Razor *(that's what I have some experience with)* to render the data into the markup I return on page load. Or I'd do both, render the data into the markup I return and then update it via js/ajax.

Comment: You can use web method.